citus + patroni coordinator setup issue
We want to setup patroni HA setup with 3 coordinator, 2 worker node 1 & 2 worker node 2.
I am getting system id mismatch when i start 2nd coordinator. First one is running fine, only facing issue while running the 2nd coordinator while joining the cluster.
Below is my patroni.yml file.
I tried deleting data directory and also removing key from etcd and start again. But it is the same issue.
scope: demo
name: ${INSTANCE_NAME}
namespace: /service/

citus:
  group: ${CITUS_GROUP}   # 0 for coordinator and 1, 2, 3, etc for workers
  database: citus  # must be the same on all nodes

restapi:
  listen: 0.0.0.0:8008
  connect_address: ${INVENTORY_HOSTNAME}:8008

etcd3:
  hosts: ${PATRONI_ETCD_HOSTS}

bootstrap:
  method: initdb
  dcs:
    ttl: 30
    loop_wait: 10
    retry_timeout: 10
    maximum_lag_on_failover: 1048576
    master_start_timeout: 300
    synchronous_mode: false
    synchronous_mode_strict: false
    synchronous_node_count: 1
    postgresql:
      use_pg_rewind: true
      use_slots: true
      parameters:
        max_connections: 1000
        superuser_reserved_connections: 5
        password_encryption: md5
        max_locks_per_transaction: 512
        max_prepared_transactions: 0
        huge_pages: try
        shared_buffers: 512MB
        effective_cache_size: 1024MB
        work_mem: 512MB
        maintenance_work_mem: 256MB
        checkpoint_timeout: 15min
        checkpoint_completion_target: 0.9
        min_wal_size: 2GB
        max_wal_size: 8GB
        wal_buffers: 16MB
        default_statistics_target: 1000
        seq_page_cost: 1
        random_page_cost: 1.1
        effective_io_concurrency: 200
        synchronous_commit: on
        autovacuum: on
        autovacuum_max_workers: 5
        autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor: 0.01
        autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor: 0.01
        autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit: 500
        autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay: 2
        autovacuum_naptime: 1s
        max_files_per_process: 4096
        archive_mode: on
        archive_timeout: 1800s
        archive_command: cd .
        wal_level: logical
        wal_keep_size: 2GB
        max_wal_senders: 10
        max_replication_slots: 10
        hot_standby: on
        wal_log_hints: on
        wal_compression: on
        shared_preload_libraries: pg_stat_statements,auto_explain
        pg_stat_statements.max: 10000
        pg_stat_statements.track: all
        pg_stat_statements.track_utility: false
        pg_stat_statements.save: true
        auto_explain.log_min_duration: 10s
        auto_explain.log_analyze: true
        auto_explain.log_buffers: true
        auto_explain.log_timing: false
        auto_explain.log_triggers: true
        auto_explain.log_verbose: true
        auto_explain.log_nested_statements: true
        auto_explain.sample_rate: 0.01
        track_io_timing: on
        log_lock_waits: on
        log_temp_files: 0
        track_activities: on
        track_activity_query_size: 4096
        track_counts: on
        track_functions: all
        log_checkpoints: on
        logging_collector: on
        log_truncate_on_rotation: on
        log_rotation_age: 1d
        log_rotation_size: 0
        log_line_prefix: '%t [%p-%l] %r %q%u@%d '
        log_filename: postgresql-%a.log
        log_directory: /var/log/postgresql
        hot_standby_feedback: on
        max_standby_streaming_delay: 30s
        wal_receiver_status_interval: 10s
        idle_in_transaction_session_timeout: 10min
        jit: off
        max_worker_processes: 24
        max_parallel_workers: 10
        max_parallel_workers_per_gather: 2
        max_parallel_maintenance_workers: 2
        tcp_keepalives_count: 10
        tcp_keepalives_idle: 300
        tcp_keepalives_interval: 30
        citus.enable_change_data_capture: 'on'
        citus.max_client_connections: 300
      slots:
        demo_slot:
          type: logical
          database: demo
          plugin: pgoutput

  initdb:
    - encoding: UTF8
    - locale: en_US.UTF-8
    - data-checksums

  pg_hba:
    - host replication ${PATRONI_REPLICATION_USERNAME} 127.0.0.1/32 md5
    - host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5

postgresql:
  listen: 0.0.0.0:5432
  connect_address: ${INVENTORY_HOSTNAME}:5432
  use_unix_socket: true
  data_dir: /data/postgresql
  bin_dir: /usr/lib/postgresql/16/bin
  config_dir: /etc/postgresql/16/main
  pgpass: /tmp/pgpass
  authentication:
    replication:
      username: ${PATRONI_REPLICATION_USERNAME}
      password: ${PATRONI_REPLICATION_PASSWORD}
    superuser:
      username: ${PATRONI_SUPERUSER_USERNAME}
      password: ${PATRONI_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD}
  parameters:
    unix_socket_directories: /var/run/postgresql
  remove_data_directory_on_rewind_failure: false
  remove_data_directory_on_diverged_timelines: false

  create_replica_methods:
    - basebackup
  basebackup:
    max-rate: '1000M'
    checkpoint: fast

watchdog:
  mode: automatic
  device: /dev/watchdog
  safety_margin: 5

tags:
  nosync: false
  noloadbalance: false
  nofailover: false
  clonefrom: false

On 2nd coordinator, i also tried remove method: initdb and its arguments as well.

Are you configuring slave node using initdb?If yes,that is not correct way you will get system id mismatch,you should take backup from master node.

No, while setting up slave node, i remove method and initdb config from patroni.yml. Still i get the same error. @manjunath
